# Does a Java Swing Window (in Fullscreen) affect the HDMI output of a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: java, swing, hdmi

The simple Problem: i have a RaspPi3 hooked to a TV (via HDMI) and on that a java Swing application in fullscreen (remote client to show simple text as a slide show). The TV, however, goes into standby after ~60 seconds, but only if my app is running. If i simply display the desktop the TV just stays alive.

The Question is: does a fullscreen swing app mess with the HDMI signal, so that the TV thinks there is nothing more to show and shuts down? (Or is there something wrong with the way i approach the function of displaying text? See code below*)

Or is it a problem with the TV because the signal stays the same and doesnt change or isn't strong enough over ~60 seconds (too much "blank" space because the screen is mostly black)?

Note: My app does work as intended on a pure functionally basis. This standby behavior is a "bug" that i did not expect.

I don't have that deep insight of the HDMI spec, so if anyone could give me a hint on how to solve this problem, i would appreciate it.

This is my first question and i decided to ask it because i didnt found any similar problem to mine. I am not entirely sure if this question is to specific, so i apologize in advance if it is.

*Code:

```
public GUIController()
    {
        Statics.GUIC = this;
        jf = new JFrame("SP-MultiMonitor@arm " + Statics.VERSION_INFOS);
        jf.setUndecorated((Statics.PROPERTIES.getProperty("p.undecorated").equals("true")));
        jf.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        jf.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(Statics.PROPERTIES.getProperty("p.pos.x")), Integer.parseInt(Statics.PROPERTIES.getProperty("p.pos.y")));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Container cp = jf.getContentPane();
        MyCanvas tl = new MyCanvas();
        tl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        cp.add(tl);
        cp.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        jf.setSize(Integer.parseInt(Statics.PROPERTIES.getProperty("p.width")), Integer.parseInt(Statics.PROPERTIES.getProperty("p.height")));
        jf.setVisible(true);
        t = 0;

        timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                //check cmd
                switch (Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD)
                {

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_EMPTY:

                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_RUN;
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_RUN:
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_START:
                        tl.repaint();
                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_RUN;
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_STOP:
                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD_ADD = null;
                        tl.repaint();
                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_EMPTY;
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_NEXT:

                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_RUN;
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_PREV:

                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_RUN;
                        break;

                    case Statics.REND_CMD_GOTO:

                        Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD = Statics.REND_CMD_RUN;
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        jf.addWindowListener(new WindowListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                timer.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }
        });
        timer.setInitialDelay(1000);
        timer.start();
    }

    public void toggleVisibility()
    {
        jf.setVisible(!jf.isVisible());
    }
}

class MyCanvas extends JComponent
{

    int fontSize = 50;
    Font font = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if (g instanceof Graphics2D)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            if (Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD_ADD == null && Connection.getInstance().hasConnected())
            {
                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2.setFont(font);

                g2.drawString("connected", 50, 50);
                return;
            }
            else if (Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD_ADD == null)
            {

                g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2.setFont(font);

                g2.drawString("not connected", 50, 50);
                return;
            }

            String[] content = Statics.PRESENTATION_CMD_ADD.split(Statics.STRING_LIMITER_HASH);

            g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g2.setFont(font);
            for (int i = 0; i < content.length; i++)
            {
                g2.drawString(content[i], 50, fontSize + fontSize * i + 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation yet to comment, so will need to post as an answer.

I've not even looked at your code but i was having a similar issue when working on the Pi a while back, i was displaying video with image overlays(digital signage). When i went full screen i would get a flicker of the image before the screen would go black and eventually time out and the screen would go to standby.

It turned out to be an issue with the hdmi buffer or something. I never actually solved my issue, i think i just hit the limits of the raspberry pi.

What did work was turning down the resolution.  in config.txt on the sd card image i think i changed hdmi mode to 34, this gave me 1920x1280p at 30hz and opposed to 60hz, essentially doubling the buffer. There was a slight loss in quality but barely noticeable.

Sorry i can't be more help, just thought i'd add my 2cents in case it nudges you in the right direction.